# Finding the closest point to a list of points

Tags: python, performance, numpy, clustering

I'm trying to find the closest point (Euclidean distance) from a user-inputted point to a list of 50,000 points that I have. Note that the list of points changes all the time. and the closest distance depends on when and where the user clicks on the point.

```
#find the nearest point from a given point to a large list of points

import numpy as np

def distance(pt_1, pt_2):
    pt_1 = np.array((pt_1[0], pt_1[1]))
    pt_2 = np.array((pt_2[0], pt_2[1]))
    return np.linalg.norm(pt_1-pt_2)

def closest_node(node, nodes):
    pt = []
    dist = 9999999
    for n in nodes:
        if distance(node, n) <= dist:
            dist = distance(node, n)
            pt = n
    return pt

a = []
for x in range(50000):
    a.append((np.random.randint(0,1000),np.random.randint(0,1000)))

some_pt = (1, 2)

closest_node(some_pt, a)
```

Comment: I was working on a similar problem and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818546/finding-index-of-nearest-point-in-numpy-arrays-of-x-and-y-coordinates).  Also, [`Scipy.spatial.KDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) is the way to go for such approaches.

Comment: The part that says "the list changes all the time" can be expanded a bit, which might hint some ideas to increase the code performance maybe. Is the list updated randomly, or some points are added every some-seconds, and some points are lost?

Comment: The ball tree method in scikit-learn does this efficiently if the same set of points has to be searched through repeatedly. The points are sorted into a tree structure in a preprocessing step to make finding the closest point quicker. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It will certainly be faster if you vectorize the distance calculations:

```
def closest_node(node, nodes):
    nodes = np.asarray(nodes)
    dist_2 = np.sum((nodes - node)**2, axis=1)
    return np.argmin(dist_2)
```

There may be some speed to gain, and a lot of clarity to lose, by using one of the dot product functions:

```
def closest_node(node, nodes):
    nodes = np.asarray(nodes)
    deltas = nodes - node
    dist_2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', deltas, deltas)
    return np.argmin(dist_2)
```

Ideally, you would already have your list of point in an array, not a list, which will speed things up a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you mind explaining why the two methods are faster? I'm just curious as I don't come from a CS background

Comment: Python for loops are very slow. When you run operations using numpy on all items of a vector, there are hidden loops running in C under the hood, which are much, much faster.

Answer (score 26):

All your code could be rewritten as:

```
from numpy import random
from scipy.spatial import distance

def closest_node(node, nodes):
    closest_index = distance.cdist([node], nodes).argmin()
    return nodes[closest_index]

a = random.randint(1000, size=(50000, 2))

some_pt = (1, 2)

closest_node(some_pt, a)
```

---

You can just write `randint(1000)` instead of `randint(0, 1000)`, the documentation of [`randint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) says:

> If `high` is `None` (the default), then results are from `[0, low)`.

You can use the `size` argument to `randint` instead of the loop and two function calls. So:

```
a = []
for x in range(50000):
    a.append((np.random.randint(0,1000),np.random.randint(0,1000)))
```

Becomes:

```
a = np.random.randint(1000, size=(50000, 2))
```

It's also much faster (twenty times faster in my tests).

---

More importantly, `scipy` has the `scipy.spatial.distance` module that contains the [`cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) function:

> `cdist(XA, XB, metric='euclidean', p=2, V=None, VI=None, w=None)`
>
> Computes distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs.

So calculating the `distance` in a loop is no longer needed.

You use the for loop also to find the position of the minimum, but this can be done with the [`argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmin.html) method of the `ndarray` object.

Therefore, your `closest_node` function can be defined simply as:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def closest_node(node, nodes):
    return nodes[cdist([node], nodes).argmin()]
```

---

I've compared the execution times of all the `closest_node` functions defined in this question:

```
Original:
1 loop, best of 3: 1.01 sec per loop

Jaime v1:
100 loops, best of 3: 3.32 msec per loop

Jaime v2:
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 msec per loop

Mine:
100 loops, best of 3: 2.07 msec per loop
```

All vectorized functions perform hundreds of times faster than the original solution.

`cdist` is outperformed only by the second function by Jaime, but only slightly.
Certainly `cdist` is the simplest.

Answer (score 6):

By using a [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) computing the distance between all points it's not needed for this type of query. It's also [built in into scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) and can speed up these types of programs enormously going from O(n^2) to O(log n), if you're doing many queries. If you only make one query, the time constructing the tree will dominate the computation time.

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import numpy as np
n = 10
v = np.random.rand(n, 3)
kdtree = KDTree(v)
d, i = kdtree.query((0,0,0))
print("closest point:", v[i])
```